# Varchar takes zero field empty

Tags: pdo

I have a table with a series of codes, which has a field called "numerousuarios" which has a default value "0"

Here the code:

```
$statement = " SELECT numerousuarios FROM codigos WHERE codigos = :codigo";
$sth = $db ->prepare($statement);
$sth -> execute(array(':codigo'=>$codigo));
$result = $sth->fetch();
$mivariable = $result[numerousuarios];
if(!empty($mivariable)){
  if($mivariable>=5){
    echo "the code is full users"; 
  }
   else{
     // Do something...
   }
}
else{
  echo "el codigo no existe";
}
```

The if (empty ($ myvar)) is to see if that record in the database.

The problem is that if the value is "0" I take it as an empty field.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the result is "0" by default .just check the returend value is **not equal 0**  :)

```
$statement = " SELECT numerousuarios FROM codigos WHERE codigos = :codigo";
$sth = $db ->prepare($statement);
$sth -> execute(array(':codigo'=>$codigo));
$result = $sth->fetch();
$mivariable = $result[numerousuarios];
if($mivariable !=0){
  if($mivariable>=5){
    echo "the code is full users"; 
  }
   else{
     // Do something...
   }
}
else{
  echo "el codigo no existe";
}
```

:)

Comment: I'm sorry, I just edited my ask, please mention that the condition also includes code that is not greater than 5 Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for not answering, I'm in college and I have not had a chance to test the code, when I get home I try and I mention, thanks!